# Populating a list with elements from different lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm looking to generate a list by reading in information from other lists. The list will be of the form `maindot =[dot1[0], dot2[0], ...]` taking the information from the `dot1` etc lists, e.g.

```
dot1=[2,4,34], dot2=[3,45,4],
```

which will be in a separate parameter file. The number of dot lists will be specified by the user as n.

How do I write it so that python 'knows' the number of dot lists given in the parameter file?

Comment: How do you get lists `dot1, dot2`, etc. without knowing in advance how many there are? You almost certainly need to collect them all into a list of lists (which will be of length `n`), and then the solution to your problem will be different (and simple). Give more information about your parameter file and we'll set you straight.

Comment: so my parameter file looks like this: 

n=2 #number of dot lists 
dot1 = [34, 300, 5,6,7,0]
dot2 = [22, 300, 4,3,7,0]

and the user can increase n and add another list

Comment: I don't see anything... Edit your question to paste in the information.

Comment: But basically your goal is to build a list of lists from the parameter file, then use the last version of Kasra's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` function to get the columns from arbitrary number of iterables :

```
>>> dot1=[2,4,34]
>>> dot2=[3,45,4]
>>> zip(dot1,dot2)
[(2, 3), (4, 45), (34, 4)]
```

And of you want to put the first index of you lists within another list you can just get the first index of `zip(dot1,dot2)`:

```
new_list=zip(dot1,dot2)[0]
```

Note that in python 3 `zip` returns a generator so you can use `next` function to access the fist index :

```
new_list=next(zip(dot1,dot2))
```

And if you have a lot of list you can put all of them with a list and pass them all by unpacking operation to `zip` function :

```
new_list=zip(*main_list)[0]
```

Comment: but how do i do it up to n lists?

Comment: The number of lists isn't fixed, it's user defined. So I need to hardcode a solution that can handle that.

Comment: @h_user Its not important just put the input lists within a `main_list` and pass it to `zip` function.